# Was bedeutet „sich zu schaffen machen“?

Tags: idiom

In Lew Tolstois *Anna Karenina* heißt es:

> … der Tatar, der die Gläser wieder gefüllt hatte und *sich* um die beiden gerade dann *zu schaffen machte*, wenn seine Anwesenheit nicht mehr erwünscht war …

Was bedeutet hier *sich zu schaffen machen*?

Comment: Steht im Wörterbuch (z.B. LEO: хлопота́ть); ich stimme dafür, die Frage zu schließen.

Comment: Wichtig ist in dem Zusammenhang, dass man sich grundsätzlich *an etwas* oder *um etwas* zu schaffen macht. In diesem Fall sind das "die beiden".

Comment: @chirlu: ich habe mehrere Probleme mit deinem Kommentar und Close Vote. 1. In meiner Online-Ausgabe von LEO erscheint in der Übersetzung von хлопота́ть nicht *sich um **jemanden** zu schaffen machen*. 2. "Sich um jemanden zu schaffen machen" ist veraltet und wird heute nicht mehr verwendet ein Wörterbucheintrag ist also eher nicht die Regel 3. Seit wann verlangen wir, dass User hier Wörterbücher in mehreren Sprachen (Russisch) konsultieren müssen, bevor ihre Frage akzeptiert wird?

Comment: Nur nebenbei: Gibt es nur eine Übersetzung von Anna Karenina? Oder schrieb Tolstoi selbst auf Deutsch?

Comment: Lew Tolstoi schrieb bestimmt auf Russisch und manchmal auf Französisch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Ausdruck *sich um jemanden zu schaffen machen* bedeutet, wie die bisherigen Antworten bereits ausdrücken, *sich um jemanden bemühen/kümmern*; vielleicht noch besser *sich um jemandes Wohlergehen sorgen*. Heutzutage ist er ein bisschen aus der Mode geraten.

Wesentlich häufiger liest man *sich an etwas zu schaffen machen*, was bedeutet, dass man anfängt, an einem Gegenstand zu werkeln oder sonst wie etwas zu tun. Stünde da nicht *um die beiden*, sondern *um den beiden*, könnte man den Satz auch so verstehen, dass der Tatar jetzt anfängt, den Tisch abzuräumen, und alleine dadurch stört. Allerdings vermute ich eher, dass die traditionelle Bedeutung gemeint ist, wonach er auch etwas tat, das eine Reaktion der beiden zur Folge gehabt haben könnte (fragen, ob etwas fehlt; etwas mündlich anbieten etc.).

Comment: "Heutzutage ist er ein bisschen aus der Mode geraten." - *ein bisschen*, ja ... als Muttersprachler aus Deutschland kannte ich den Ausdruck nicht und hatte auch keine Ahnung, was damit gemeint sein sollte. Ich hätte ihn vermutlich so interpretiert, wie du es für "um den beiden" erklärt hättest. Danke für die Erklärung in dieser Antwort!

Answer (score 2):

sich um die beiden bemühte bzw. sich um die beiden kümmerte

Answer (score 2):

Auf Russisch hat Tolstoi "вертеться" (ich habe überprüft) geschrieben. Wörtlich bedeutet das „drehen“... eine kreisförmige, rotierende Bewegung auszuführen.
Das bedeutet, dass jemand hier und da gelaufen ist, möglicherweise etwas getan hat oder eine Aktivität von sich gegeben hat.  Bewegen Sie sich ständig im Raum.  Dieses Wort bedeutet auch „sich drehen“, Verbindungen in Geschäftskreisen haben.  Oder jemand, der keinen festen Job hat, ist ständig auf der Suche nach Nahrung.

Der Kellner war sichtbar und irgendwo in der Nähe.  Ständig auf sie zugekommen oder vorbeigegangen.  Er wollte ihnen dienen.  Aber er war nicht unbedingt aufdringlich.

Comment: Interessanterweise benutzen wir im Deutschen ja auch *drehen* in ähnlichem Zusammenhang: *Alles, was er tat, drehte sich um die beiden.*

Answer (score 1):

It means, to work on something or to pay attention to. In this sentence, the Tartar (apparently a servant) was putting effort into on paying attention to two people when he was not desired.

Answer (score 0):

*Sich [an oder um etwas] zu schaffen machen* bedeutet zunächst einmal, dass man sich unnötige Arbeit macht. (*Schaffen* ist ein verbreitetes Wort für *arbeiten* in südlichen Dialekten.) Wichtig sind bei dieser Wendung aber die starken Konnotationen.  Wenn man sich *an* einem Objekt zu schaffen macht, hantiert man damit, oder berührt es zumindest. Es handelt sich meist um eine verstohlene, erkennbar illegale oder zumindest verdächtige Tätigkeit. Wenn man sich *um* jemand oder etwas zu schaffen macht, findet eine vorgeschobene legitime Arbeit in der Nähe des Objekts statt. Letzteres wird heute kaum noch verwendet.

- Der Dieb machte sich an dem Auto zu schaffen. Nachdem der die Tür aufgebrochen hatte, öffnete er sie und nahm eine Handtasche heraus.
- (Veraltet.) Der Räuber machte sich mit Werbeflyern um das Auto zu schaffen. Als der zurückgekehrte Besitzer es gerade aufgeschlossen hatte, griff der Räuber sich den Schlüssel, drängte sich auf den Vordersitz und fuhr mit quietschenden Reifen davon.